# Input validation of two conditions

Tags: python, validation

I'm working on validating inputs in python. 
This is the code I have so far:

```
while input('Would you like to continue(y=yes/n=no)') not in ('y'): 
      print ("Sorry, I didnt catch that. Enter again: ")
```

The code works but I want to use two conditions, one for 'y' and one for 'n'.

Comment: The top answer to the that question I linked above shows how to store what the input is, then you can check it to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while True:

    ## Get their choicer
    selection = input('Your message')

    ## If yes
    if selection == 'y':
        do_something_for_y()

    ## If no
    elif selection == 'n':
        do_something_for_n()

    ## If neither, this loops to the top and asks again
```